# csv.DictReader and Session.bulk_save_objects?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, sqlalchemy

Python 3.8 w/ SQLAlchemy 1.3 (MySQL 8)

- [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)
- [Session.bulk_save_objects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects)

Table definition:

[image]

Before you ask, I cannot provide the csv as it contains sensitive data. It's a "normal" csv file with 0x0A (\n) as the newline character. When opening in text mode, `DictReader` works but `bulk_save_objects` fails.

First, I download the files from S3:

```
def download_files(bucket, keys):
    filenames = []
    for key in keys:
        filename = key.split('/')[-1]
        filenames.append(filename)
        with open(f'data/{filename}', mode='wb') as f:
            bucket.download_fileobj(key, f)
    return filenames
```

Without `mode='wb'`:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Then, I parse the file and save:

```
def parse_files(filenames):
    objects = []
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(f'data/{filename}', mode='rb') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                row['movie_studios'] = row['movie_studios'].strip('"[]')
                obj = Outbound(filename=filename, **row)
                objects.append(obj)
    session.bulk_save_objects(objects)
    session.commit()
```

With `mode='rb'`:

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Without `mode='rb'` and with `[encoding='utf-8', ]newline=''`:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 30-33: character maps to <undefined>
```

Without `mode='rb'` and with `encoding='ascii', newline=''`:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6658: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried io.TextIOWrapper:

```
with open(f'data/{filename}', mode='rb') as f:
    with io.TextIOWrapper(f, encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 30-33: character maps to <undefined>
```

Not surprising...

It seems to be failing on this character:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the connection encoding of SQLAlchemy to make sure its using `utf-8` and not `asci`. For example, specify the [`charset`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#unicode) like it shows in their exampple:

```
e = create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test?charset=utf8mb4")
```